# guardar fotos y datos con php y mysql

Tags: php

Hola estoy haciendo unos ajustes a un sitio web  de control de inventarios y me piden que cree una opcion para ponerle fotos a los productos y  que al editar los datos del producto se pueda editar tambien la foto entre otras cosas, pero en esto es en lo que me he estancado.Ya en el codigo esta que se vea la imagen que le asigno al producto desde la base de datos

```
<img src="<?php echo $row['foto' ]?>">
```

esto funciona bien , el problema es que al completar el formulario, no c guarda la imagen en la carpeta que le asigno, todos los demas datos como nombre , id , etc  se guardan sin problemas

y me da estos errorer:

```
Notice: Undefined index: mod_foto in C:\xampp\htdocs\ajax\editar_producto.php on line 63

Notice: Undefined index: mod_foto in C:\xampp\htdocs\ajax\editar_producto.php on line 64

Notice: Undefined index: mod_foto in C:\xampp\htdocs\ajax\editar_producto.php on line 65

Notice: Undefined index: mod_foto in C:\xampp\htdocs\ajax\editar_producto.php on line 66
```

Archivos

```
<?php
    include('is_logged.php');//Archivo verifica que el usario que intenta acceder a la URL esta logueado
/*Inicia validacion del lado del servidor*/
    if (empty($_POST['mod_id'])) {
           $errors[] = "ID vacío";
        }else if (empty($_POST['mod_codigo'])) {
           $errors[] = "Código vacío";
        } else if (empty($_POST['mod_nombre'])){
            $errors[] = "Nombre del producto vacío";
        } else if ($_POST['mod_categoria']==""){
            $errors[] = "Selecciona la categoría del producto";
        } else if (empty($_POST['mod_precio'])){
            $errors[] = "Precio de venta vacío";
        } else if (
            !empty($_POST['mod_id']) &&
            !empty($_POST['mod_codigo']) &&
            !empty($_POST['mod_nombre']) &&
            $_POST['mod_categoria']!="" &&
            !empty($_POST['mod_precio'])
        ){
        /* Connect To Database*/
        require_once ("../config/db.php");//Contiene las variables de configuracion para conectar a la base de datos
        require_once ("../config/conexion.php");//Contiene funcion que conecta a la base de datos
        // escaping, additionally removing everything that could be (html/javascript-) code
        /*$tamanioPermitido = 200 * 1024;

//Tenemos una lista con las extensiones que aceptaremos
$extensionesPermitidas = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png");

//Obtenemos la extensión del archivo
$extension = explode(".", $_FILES["mod_foto"]["name"]);

//Validamos el tipo de archivo, el tamaño en bytes y que la extensión sea válida
if ((($_FILES["mod_foto"]["type"] == "image/gif")
      || ($_FILES["mod_foto"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
      || ($_FILES["mod_foto"]["type"] == "image/png")
      || ($_FILES["mod_foto"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg"))
      && ($_FILES["mod_foto"]["size"] < $tamanioPermitido)
      && in_array($extension, $extensionesPermitidas)){
              //Si no hubo un error al subir el archivo temporalmente
              if ($_FILES["mod_foto"]["error"] > 0){
                     echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["mod_foto"]["error"] . "<br />";
              }
              else{
                    //Si el archivo ya existe se muestra el mensaje de error
                    if (file_exists("../img/productos/" . $_FILES["mod_foto"]["name"])){
                           echo $_FILES["mod_foto"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
                    }
                    else{
                           //Se mueve el archivo de su ruta temporal a una ruta establecida
                           move_uploaded_file($_FILES["mod_foto"]["tmp_name"],
                                   "../img/productos/" . $_FILES["mod_foto"]["name"]);

                    }
              }
}
else{
     echo "Archivo inválido";
}
    */
    $variable = isset($_POST['mod_foto'])? $_POST['mod_foto']:'';
    print_r($variable);
    if ((($_FILES["mod_foto"]["type"] == "image/gif")
      || ($_FILES["mod_foto"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
      || ($_FILES["mod_foto"]["type"] == "image/png")
      || ($_FILES["mod_foto"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg"))
      && ($_FILES["mod_foto"]["size"] < $tamanioPermitido)
      && in_array($extension, $extensionesPermitidas)){
              //Si no hubo un error al subir el archivo temporalmente
              if ($_FILES["mod_foto"]["error"] > 0){
                     echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["mod_foto"]["error"] . "<br />";
              }
              else{
                    //Si el archivo ya existe se muestra el mensaje de error
                    if (file_exists("../img/productos/" . $_FILES["mod_foto"]["name"])){
                           echo $_FILES["mod_foto"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
                    }
                    else{
                           //Se mueve el archivo de su ruta temporal a una ruta establecida
                           move_uploaded_file($_FILES["mod_foto"]["tmp_name"],
                                   "../img/productos/" . $_FILES["mod_foto"]["name"]);
                                    }
              }
}

    $ruta='img/productos/';

        $codigo=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_POST["mod_codigo"],ENT_QUOTES)));
        $nombre=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_POST["mod_nombre"],ENT_QUOTES)));
        $descripcion=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_POST["mod_descripcion"],ENT_QUOTES)));
        $categoria=intval($_POST['mod_categoria']);
        $stock=intval($_POST['mod_stock']);
        $precio_venta=floatval($_POST['mod_precio']);
        $id_producto=$_POST['mod_id'];
        $sql="UPDATE products SET codigo_producto='".$codigo."', nombre_producto='".$nombre."', id_categoria='".$categoria."', precio_producto='".$precio_venta."', stock='".$stock."', descripcion='".$descripcion."', foto='".$ruta."' WHERE id_producto='".$id_producto."'";
        $query_update = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
            if ($query_update){
                $messages[] = "Producto ha sido actualizado satisfactoriamente.";
            } else{
                $errors []= "Lo siento algo ha salido mal intenta nuevamente.".mysqli_error($con);
            }
        } else {
            $errors []= "Error desconocido.";
        }

        if (isset($errors)){

            ?>
            <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
                    <strong>Error!</strong> 
                    <?php
                        foreach ($errors as $error) {
                                echo $error;
                            }
                        ?>
            </div>
            <?php
            }
            if (isset($messages)){

                ?>
                <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
                        <strong>¡Bien hecho!</strong>
                        <?php
                            foreach ($messages as $message) {
                                    echo $message;
                                }
                            ?>
                </div>
                <?php
            }

?>
```

este es el html del formulario

```
<?php
    if (isset($con))
    {
?>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></i> Editar producto</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" id="editar_producto" name="editar_producto" action="editar_producto.php"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div id="resultados_ajax2"></div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="mod_codigo" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Código</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="mod_codigo" name="mod_codigo" placeholder="Código del producto" required>
                <input type="hidden" name="mod_id" id="mod_id">
            </div>
          </div>
           <div class="form-group">
            <label for="mod_nombre" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Nombre</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
              <textarea class="form-control" id="mod_nombre" name="mod_nombre" placeholder="Nombre del producto" required></textarea>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="mod_categoria" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Categoría</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <select class='form-control' name='mod_categoria' id='mod_categoria' required>
                    <option value="">Selecciona una categoría</option>
                        <?php 
                        $query_categoria=mysqli_query($con,"select * from categorias order by nombre_categoria");
                        while($rw=mysqli_fetch_array($query_categoria)) {
                            ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $rw['id_categoria'];?>"><?php echo $rw['nombre_categoria'];?></option>            
                            <?php
                        }
                        ?>
                </select>             
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="mod_precio" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Precio</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="mod_precio" name="mod_precio" placeholder="Precio de venta del producto" required pattern="^[0-9]{1,5}(\.[0-9]{0,2})?$" title="Ingresa sólo números con 0 ó 2 decimales" maxlength="8">
            </div>
          </div>

         <div class="form-group">
            <label for="mod_stock" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Stock</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
              <input type="number" min="0" class="form-control" id="mod_stock" name="mod_stock" placeholder="Inventario inicial" required  maxlength="8" readonly>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="mod_descripcion" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Descripci&oacute;n del Producto</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
              <textarea class="form-control" id="mod_descripcion" name="mod_descripcion" placeholder="Descripci&oacute;n del producto" ></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <p>
          <label for="mod_foto" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Insertar Foto del Producto</label>
          <div class="col-sm-8">


          <input id="mod_foto" type="file" name="mod_foto" />

      </div>
          </div>


      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="actualizar_datos">Actualizar datos</button>
      </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<?php
    }
?>
```

Gracias y saludos

Answer (score 0):

hay varios errores en tu código

1.- El error que indicas dice que tu campo "mod_foto" no esta llegando a tu backend.
Primero tienes que validar que estas mandando el request $_FILES

```
if ($_FILES){
```

con eso te dejara de dar ese error, pero ahora hay que revisar por que no llega, lo más seguro es que en tu formulario no tiene el enctype correcto

debe quedar así:

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

si no colocas el multipart/form-data, aunque tengas un input file este no se mandará.

luego en tu validador en la parte de extensiones permitidas haces un explode para obtener la extension del archivo pero pero le pasas un array

```
in_array($extension, $extensionesPermitidas)) //esto es incorrecto

in_array($extension[1], $extensionesPermitidas)) // esto es lo correcto
```

el 1 es por que al explotar los nombres obtienes esto ['nombre de archivo', '.jpg'] donde $extension[0] => 'nombre de archivo' y $extension[1] => '.jpg' así ya valida correctamente.
Por último, si tienes problemas con el move upload, puedes agregarle un **DIR** para que se mueva a la ruta que deseas. así quedó el código con todos los cambios que hice y me funciona. Espero te sea de ayuda.

```
<!-- Formulario html (Omití los otros campos por comodidad) -->
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="mod_foto" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Insertar Foto del Producto</label>
<input id="mod_foto" type="file" name="mod_foto" />

<input type="submit" name="">
```

```
$tamanioPermitido = 200 * 1024;
//Tenemos una lista con las extensiones que aceptaremos
$extensionesPermitidas = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png");

//Validamos el tipo de archivo, el tamaño en bytes y que la extensión sea válida 
if ($_FILES){
    //Obtenemos la extensión del archivo
    $extension = explode(".", $_FILES["mod_foto"]["name"]);
    //Si no hubo un error al subir el archivo temporalmente 
    if ((
        ($_FILES["mod_foto"]["type"] == "image/gif")      ||
        ($_FILES["mod_foto"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")     ||
        ($_FILES["mod_foto"]["type"] == "image/png")      ||
        ($_FILES["mod_foto"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg"))   &&
        ($_FILES["mod_foto"]["size"] < $tamanioPermitido) &&
        in_array($extension[1], $extensionesPermitidas))
    {
        if ($_FILES["mod_foto"]["error"] > 0){
            echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["mod_foto"]["error"] . "";
        } else { //Si el archivo ya existe se muestra el mensaje de error
            if (file_exists(__DIR__."/img/productos/" . $_FILES["mod_foto"]["name"])){
                echo $_FILES["mod_foto"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
            } else { //Se mueve el archivo de su ruta temporal a una ruta establecida
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["mod_foto"]["tmp_name"], __DIR__."/img/productos/" . $_FILES["mod_foto"]["name"]);
            }
        }
    } else{
        echo "Archivo inválido";
    }
}
```

Comment: primero que todo gracias, con eso ya no me muestra los errores anteriores ,ya coloque el multipart/form-data en el codigo  y reajuste el php de la forma que me indicas , el unico problema que tengo ahora es q la imagen sigue sin guardarse en la ubicacion que indico ,sabes que otros problemas podrian causar esto?,  en el php.ini puse el file_uploads on y la carpeta existe , no se realmente que puede pasar

Comment: Lo más fácil es colocar la ruta absoluta de tu folder, eso lo consigo con el __DIR__ trata de imprimir echo __DIR__."tu_ ruta" para ver cual es la ruta que imprime, con eso te das una idea de cual puede ser el problema.

Comment: el problema por lo que veo es que no estoy muy familiarizado con ajax y no se como funciona y ahi vienen los problemas porque hice un formulario para probar el codigo y las imagenes se guardan y se muestran bien tengo que estudiar bien  como el sitio y como utilizar ajax